# Py2Exe and pkg_resources.iter_entry_points()

Tags: python, py2exe, review-board

I'm attempting to use Py2Exe to build a Windows executable from ReviewBoard's postreview.py, so my users don't need to install Python in order to post review requests.

I'm running up against a problem in which the compiled version can't find any registered SCM clients.  I've tracked this down to the following line in the code:

```
for ep in pkg_resources.iter_entry_points(group='rbtools_scm_clients'):
```

These entry points are listed in the RBTools egg in EGG-INFO\entry_points.txt.  In the compiled exe, the iter_entry_points() function returns an empty list.

Is there any way through Py2Exe to make the compiled exe aware of these entry points?  Or am I stuck customizing postreview (essentially hard-coding the entry points) to get this to work?

Thanks for any tips!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case anyone else comes across this looking for an answer, I got it to work by hard-coding the entry points.  I had to update the `load_scmclients()` function in `rbtools/clients/__init__.py` as follows:

```
import imp
def main_is_frozen():
    return (hasattr(sys, "frozen") or # new py2exe
            hasattr(sys, "importers") # old py2exe
            or imp.is_frozen("__main__")) # tools/freeze

from rbtools.clients.svn import SVNClient
from rbtools.clients.git import GitClient
from rbtools.clients.mercurial import MercurialClient
from rbtools.clients.cvs import CVSClient
from rbtools.clients.perforce import PerforceClient
from rbtools.clients.plastic import PlasticClient
from rbtools.clients.clearcase import ClearCaseClient
from rbtools.clients.bazaar import BazaarClient
def load_scmclients(options):
    global SCMCLIENTS

    SCMCLIENTS = {}

    if not main_is_frozen():
        for ep in pkg_resources.iter_entry_points(group='rbtools_scm_clients'):
            try:
                SCMCLIENTS[ep.name] = ep.load()(options=options)
            except Exception, e:
                logging.error('Could not load SCM Client "%s": %s' % (ep.name, e))
    else:
        temp_clients = {}
        temp_clients['svn'] = SVNClient
        temp_clients['git'] = GitClient
        temp_clients['mercurial'] = MercurialClient
        temp_clients['cvs'] = CVSClient
        temp_clients['perforce'] = PerforceClient
        temp_clients['plastic'] = PlasticClient
        temp_clients['clearcase'] = ClearCaseClient
        temp_clients['bazaar'] = BazaarClient
        for ep in temp_clients:
            try:
                SCMCLIENTS[ep] = temp_clients[ep](options=options)
            except Exception, e:
                logging.error('Could not load SCM Client "%s": %s' % (str(ep), e))
```